# Is the phrase 'get along with' formal enough to be used in a personal statement?

Tags: phrases

If not, can you suggest any other way to express that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by a personal statement? "Get along with" is considered normal for everyday speech, and I could imagine it being used on the floor of Congress, say, without raising eyebrows.

Comment: It's usually *get **on** with [someone* in BrE, but both sound a bit informal to me (not as much as *We **rub** along* though). You might consider ***to be on good terms with...*** as a more formal alternative.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to have more context, but in general I think that it is formal enough for most purposes.

For example, "gets along with colleagues" gets over 15,000 hits on Google. If we add "his" (gets along with his colleagues), the score is doubled. This shows how frequently it is used in different contexts.